# Replace a letter with another one using iconic

Tags: html, css

I want to change a hourglass with another on hover [ here is  the first hourglass  [BasicImg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87AsR.png)and i want to be replaced by this on hover: [AfterHover](http://fontawesome.io/icon/hourglass-half/) ]...
I try to do that with js but the problem here is this is just a letter..I mean the hourglass is just a letter - i used icon fonts...
the code for hourglass is this:

```css
.fa.fa-hourglass-start{
color:inherit;
 font-size: 28px;
 line-height: 20px;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>  
<li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-hourglass-start"></span> Istoric</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: if you want to achieve it with CSS only, you need to create custom classes that will have default icon in normal state, alternative icon in hover state. if you are fine with JavaScript, you can change classes with hovering, so no letter changing, but remove class and add new class (fa-iconname)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
a > .my-hourglass:before{content:"\f251"}
a:hover > .my-hourglass:before{content:"\f252"}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>  
<li><a href="#"><span class="fa my-hourglass"></span> Istoric</a>
</body>
</html>
```

(edited with example)
use above CSS for your icon (instead of fa-hourglass-start)

Comment: Thx a lot man.It's working, but I always wanna know what this ">" make. Select just link from that class or make something else? Thx again.

Comment: @Geov `>` meaning child of element. For example `a > .class` meaning select `.class` element that is child of `a` element.

Comment: exactly, it applies only to class directly in anchor, so if you have some other element with same icon, it won't be applied there. @Geov if my solution worked for you, please accept it ;)

Comment: I dont know how this is my first question, but I have one more question.From where u take content f251 f252?

Comment: you can find it on FontAwesome website, it's next to the icon title. Or you can just open CSS file, find the name of icon you want and there will be your content with icon code :)